# gcloud cli and custom cert path

Tags: ssl, google-cloud-platform, python-requests, gcloud, urllib3

I'm using the GCP gcloud cli tool. For 90% of my reqirements the tool works perfectly well and there are no issues at all. However, with some commands I would see an error like:

```
ERROR: gcloud crashed (SSLError): HTTPSConnectionPool(host='gcr.io', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /v2/ (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1108)')))

gcloud's default CA certificates failed to verify your connection, which can happen if you are behind a proxy or firewall.
To use a custom CA certificates file, please run the following command:
  gcloud config set core/custom_ca_certs_file /path/to/ca_certs
```

My understanding is that this is because the gcloud installations default CA certificates were unable to verify the connection. When I turn off ssl validation with:

```
gcloud config set auth/disable_ssl_validation true
```

The request/command starts to work. Great, but I also get a number of rebukes spat back at me on the stderr like this:

```
C:\Users\xxxxx\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\lib\third_party\urllib3\connectionpool.py:1043: InsecureRequestWarning: Unverified HTTPS 
request is being made to host 'gcr.io'. Adding certificate verification is strongly advised. See: https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/1.26.x/advanced-usage.html#ssl-warnings
```

Now, I understand this message. Sort of. I realise its coming from the urllib3 library and the connection pool class and can even see the strings of the error in that file. So it's clear that gcloud is just leaning into that package for the communications channel to GCP.

So this bring me back to the first error and trying to find the correct way to resolve this. I found that there is a config command:

```
gcloud config set core/custom_ca_certs_file certs.pem
```

Which apparently tells your gcloud installation to use the file 'certs.pem' to verify SSL connections (right?). So following advice which seemed to work for other posters I went to the Python certifi repo here:

```
https://github.com/certifi/python-certifi/blob/master/certifi/cacert.pem
```

And grabbed the cacart.pem file. I saved it on my pc, and used:

```
gcloud config set core/custom_ca_certs_file cacerts.pem
```

to point my gcloud at that cacerts.pem file thinking that would solve the problem as I'm now locking gcloud to a known good cert store. I saved it all, restarted terminal and retried - still the same. Rebooted and still the same.

Now I'm perplexed.

Can someone help me to understand why this would not have worked? I'm now fixated because not only am I still looking for a fix, but now, because these steps seemed correct - and exhaust all the advice I can find on the gcloud documentation pages, I'm also desperate to understand why this did NOT work. Because everything I thought I understood suggested this should have fixed it, and it didn't, I MUST have more to learn and MUST have overlooked *something*.

Can some kind soul explain, or point me in the right direction, please?

Comment: You either have a broken Python installation or a broken CLI installation. Uninstall the CLI. Reboot. Install again. Do not select any options to use your other Python installation.

Comment: @JohnHanley
Many thanks, I uninstalled gCloud (rebooting and removing all residual paths). After re-installing it using defaults and embedded / packaged Python version, it was annoyingly exactly the same. I then re-installed my Python 3.9 but again, just the same. Very frustrating.